# change Querystring value when rewriting url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a website of baby names for filtering gender I had a querystring "gender" that would have values:
0 : girl
1: boy
2: both

Now I want to rewrite the url like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/girl_names   ==>    http://www.mysite.com?gender=0
http://www.mysite.com/boy_names   ==>    http://www.mysite.com?gender=1
http://www.mysite.com/boy_and_girl_names   ==>    http://www.mysite.com?gender=2
```

in below code how can I modify the value to be 1 instead of boy, 0 instead of girl and 2 instead of boy_and_girl

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Filter By Gender" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.+)_names" /><action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?gender={R:1}"/>
    </rule>              
    <!-- some more rules-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following code..

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Filter By Gender" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.+)_names" /><action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?Gender=$1"/>
    </rule>              
    <!-- some more rules-->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

here $1 converted into your given value.

Comment: yes I know this. but the given value will be "boy" for example but I want $1 be "1" instead of "boy". I want to know if we can change the values